# Find the TV series

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography, computer-puzzle

I'm looking for a TV series. A hint is hidden in the following image:
[image]
As this is a [computer-puzzle](/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle) you might want to download the image.

Comment: Would a steganography tag be appropriate?

Comment: This is a famous picture, but I can't find any instance of it on the web whose resolution as as high as in this picture -- yet it doesn't *look* like it was upsampled from a lower-resolution original. (Nor, for what it's worth, do I see obvious differences other than resolution between this and other copies of the image on the web. But I haven't looked all that hard.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're hiding:

> South Park

Based on the fact that

> Using [this online steganography tool](http://incoherency.co.uk/image-steganography/#unhide), the following image is hidden in the LSBs (cropped from the bottom left corner):
>
>  [image: Sexual Harassment Panda]
>
>  This is a picture of the South Park character, [Sexual Harassment Panda](https://www.google.com/search?q=south+park+panda)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> Genius, the tv series.

The photograph is of

> I found the photo on wikipedia's page for the [1911 Solvay Conference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvay_Conference). The caption reads, "Photograph of the first conference in 1911 at the Hotel Metropole. Seated (L-R): W. Nernst, M. Brillouin, E. Solvay, H. Lorentz, E. Warburg, J. Perrin, W. Wien, M. Curie, and H. Poincaré. Standing (L-R): R. Goldschmidt, M. Planck, H. Rubens, A. Sommerfeld, F. Lindemann, M. de Broglie, M. Knudsen, F. Hasenöhrl, G. Hostelet, E. Herzen, J.H. Jeans, E. Rutherford, H. Kamerlingh Onnes, A. Einstein and P. Langevin."

It may only be coincidence but

> Scientists Max Plank and Albert Einstein are both in the photo and are also portrayed in a few episodes of the tv series "Genius".

Note: Not sure if this answer really fits the enigmatic/computer puzzle tags so it might be another tv series that the OP is looking for.

Comment: Can also be http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5538142/ (the city where it happened)

Answer (score -2):

The series is:

> [P.I.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P.I._(TV_series))

The reason is:

> The image file is 3.14 MB in size. Pi (π), the mathematical constant, starts with 3.14.

Comment: I shspect the questioner could have got closer to pi if that was the case